# How to selectively change elements in a list that is a value in a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm playing around with some old MLB data and trying to write some code to track the W/L record of each team. The data is organized as a bunch of rows where each sequential pair (0&1, 2&3, usw.) is the two teams that played the game.

The first six rows look like the following. (You are welcome to imagine the additional 4918 rows for yourself)

```
{'Date': {0: 401, 1: 401, 2: 401, 3: 401, 4: 401, 5: 401},
 'VH': {0: 'V', 1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'H', 4: 'V', 5: 'H'},
 'Team': {0: 'PIT', 1: 'CUB', 2: 'ATL', 3: 'PHI', 4: 'ARI', 5: 'SDG'},
 'Final': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 7, 5: 8}}
```

I created a dictionary where each team name is a key and the value for each key is the record for that team.

```
records = dict.fromkeys(MLB21_data['Team'].unique(),[0,0]) #Initialize the dictionary with [0,0] records
```

My issue is that when I make a change to one (integer) element in one list that is the value of one team then that change is made to every list that is a value in the dictionary.

Here's some sample code intended to update one team's win number in their overall record

```
i = 1
print(MLB21_data.at[i-1,'Team'])
records[MLB21_data.at[i-1,'Team']][0] += 1
print(records)
```

Here's the outcome after that one update

```
PIT
{'PIT': [1, 0], 'CUB': [1, 0], 'ATL': [1, 0], 'PHI': [1, 0], 'ARI': [1, 0], 'SDG': [1, 0], 'LAD': [1, 0], 'COL': [1, 0], 'STL': [1, 0], 'CIN': [1, 0], 'TOR': [1, 0], 'NYY': [1, 0], 'CLE': [1, 0], 'DET': [1, 0], 'TEX': [1, 0], 'KAN': [1, 0], 'CWS': [1, 0], 'LAA': [1, 0], 'HOU': [1, 0], 'OAK': [1, 0], 'MIN': [1, 0], 'MIL': [1, 0], 'TAM': [1, 0], 'MIA': [1, 0], 'SFO': [1, 0], 'SEA': [1, 0], 'BAL': [1, 0], 'BOS': [1, 0], 'NYM': [1, 0], 'WAS': [1, 0]}
```

And here's what I want after that one update

```
PIT
{'PIT': [1, 0], 'CUB': [0, 0], 'ATL': [0, 0], 'PHI': [0, 0], 'ARI': [0, 0], 'SDG': [0, 0], 'LAD': [0, 0], 'COL': [0, 0], 'STL': [0, 0], 'CIN': [0, 0], 'TOR': [0, 0], 'NYY': [0, 0], 'CLE': [0, 0], 'DET': [0, 0], 'TEX': [0, 0], 'KAN': [0, 0], 'CWS': [0, 0], 'LAA': [0, 0], 'HOU': [0, 0], 'OAK': [0, 0], 'MIN': [0, 0], 'MIL': [0, 0], 'TAM': [0, 0], 'MIA': [0, 0], 'SFO': [0, 0], 'SEA': [0, 0], 'BAL': [0, 0], 'BOS': [0, 0], 'NYM': [0, 0], 'WAS': [0, 0]}
```

As you might imagine I loop through the data to populate the dictionary.

Why am I getting the one outcome and not the other?
And what would make Python give me the outcome I want?

Comment: I just googled MLB. Apparently it refers to a sport widely known in the United States, Cuba and Canada. It will help you to get the help of the broad community if you post a [mre] avoiding some topic-specific jergon unrelated to the program itself.

Comment: The sport-specific label is not important. Anything related to that can be understood as simple variable or key values. I included code for creating the dictionary, code for updating the value, the outcome I get, and the outcome I want. What about my example is not reproducible?

Comment: I think your problem can be related to [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178).

Comment: Understanding better your problem can help us to propose an alternative approach (unless of course you only want to understand the _why_ of your bug). Even in that case, it would help to have a minimum example so we can reproduce the problem. BTW, is your data originally in a pandas dataframe? If so, consider posting the result of `df.head(5).to_dict()` so we can copy-paste it.

Comment: Ignatius, I can see how it might be the case that python thinks that every list that is a value of in the dictionary is actually the same list under the hood. OK. What's a good Pythonic way to address that?

Comment: Alright. I've updated the code with  dictionary version of the first six rows. Yes, the original data is in a dataframe. The whole program iterates through the dataframe and uses what it finds to populate the "records" dictionary.

Comment: @THill3: You use a `dict` comprehension instead, per the duplicates. `records = {x: [0, 0] for x in MLB21_data['Team'].unique()}`. Each iteration of the dictcomp reexecutes the creation of the `list` value from scratch, rather than reusing an alias to the same original `list`, so the values are truly distinct.